# How to specify features weights in a dense autoencoder?

Tags: keras, feature-selection, autoencoder

I have a list of features, each one of them has a weight (importance value), I want to build an autoencoder using 'Dense' where I set in the input layer the importance of each feature as its weight. Suppose I have the following features with their importance values:

```
feature      importance
feature_1    0.3
feature_2    0.2
feature_3    0.15
feature_4    0.05
```

Is there anyway to include these values within the input layer of the autoencoder ?

my autoencoder looks as the following

```
def generate_autoencoder(features_importance_dataframe):
    input_layer = Input(shape=(len(features_importance_dataframe.feature.unique().tolist()), ))
    
    encoder = Dense(128)(input_layer)
    encoder = Dropout(0.2)(encoder)
    encoder = Dense(64)(encoder)
    encoder = Dropout(0.2)(encoder)

    bottleneck = Dense(32)(encoder)
    bottleneck = Dropout(0.2)

    decoder = Dense(64)(bottleneck)
    decoder = Dropout(0.2)(decoder)
    decoder = Dense(128)(decoder)
    decoder = Dropout(0.2)(decoder)

    output_layer = Dense(len(features_importance_dataframe.feature.unique().tolist(), activation='sigmoid')(decoder)

    autoencoder = Model(input_layer, output_layer)
    autoencoder.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
    return autoencoder
```

Any idea of tip on how to achieve this, if feasible? Thanks.

Comment: what does "importance" mean for you here?

Comment: I generate the features' importance values using a RandomForest classifier; using entropy as information gain metric.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to have a second input layer, which gets fed with the importance information. During the learning process the model might learn the correlations between the weight value and the feature value.